# TypeError [ColorConvert]: Unable to convert color to a number

Tags: discord, discord.js

```
  client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
  // Check if the message content starts with '!commandname'.
  if (message.content.startsWith('!dadada')) {
    const Discord = require('discord.js');
    const convert = require('color-convert');

    const [color, ...messageArgs] = message.content.split(' ');
    const messageContent = messageArgs.join(' ');

    // Check if the color variable is a valid HSL color value.
    if (!color || color.split(',').length !== 3) {
      return message.channel.send("Invalid color value. Please provide a valid HSL color in the format 'hue,saturation,lightness'.");
    }

    // Convert the hue value from degrees to a percentage.
    const [hue, saturation, lightness] = color.split(',').map((string, i) => {
      if (i === 0) {
        return parseInt(string, 10) / 360;
      }
      return string;
    });

    const rgbColor = convert.hsl.rgb([hue, saturation, lightness]);

    // Create an embed with the specified color and message.
    const embed = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
      .setColor(rgbColor)
      .setDescription(messageContent);

    // Send the embed to the channel.
    message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
  }
});
```

I've been struggling for 5 hours and I can't make it :(
I didn't find any solution, do you have any idea?
Command format

!dadada 50,100%,50% text

Comment: You should omit the %s in the command, or strip them out in the command probably.